# 100% foolproof c# ftp file transfer code (with transactions if possible)

Tags: c#, transactions, ftp

I want to write a small c# ftp client class library which basically needs to transfer files to a ftp location.

What I want, is a 100% foolproof code, where I can get some sort of acknowledgement that the ftp file transfer has been either 100% successful or failed.

No resume support is required.

Good to have (but secondary):

Some sort of distributed transaction where only if the file transfer is successful for a file, i update my db for that particular file with 1 (true)... if it is failed, then db to be updated with 0 (false).

But suppose the ftp file transfer was successful, but for whatever reasons the db could not be updated, then the file over ftp should be deleted - I can easily do this using dirty c# code (where i manually try to delete the file if db update failed).

But what I am exactly looking for is file system based transaction over ftp... so both the file transfer as well as db update is not committed until both are successful (hence no need for manual delete).

Any clues?

Comment: With my little experience with FTP I would say that FTP is too primitive to actually think about transactions and foolproofness. It is also platform dependent (server platform), implementations I've seen have ugly hacks to guess the platform of the remote machine and try to interpret the garbage that is coming from over there.

Comment: exactly the problem i am currently facing... but there has to be some way out :-) unfortunately i do not have the liberty to implement webservices coz of a f**ked client

Comment: hey guys i do not understand why my question is rec. negative voting? what is so wrong with my question :-(

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this question. Have a +1 on me.

Comment: @Raj: I neither understand why the question is down voted without any comment. It's probably because of the word "code" in the question, which assumes a "give-me-the-codez" style question.

Comment: They're just going to invent a better fool if you do.

Answer (score 7):

Having had the "joy" of writing a FTP library myself here is my advice

1) Its NOT gonna be easy, because FTP servers return different return from the same command ( Like directory information,regular ftp commands and pretty much everything).
2) This is gonna take more time then you think
3) The dream about 100% foolproof transfer is not gonna happen, unless you control the FTP server and add a new FTP command so you can compare file hashes.

Pretty much if i was gonna do this again, and my goal was to transfer files ( And not learn from making the library) i would buy a already done library,

Answer (score 0):

.NET has an [FTP client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) you can use. I don't know how robust it is in the face of FTP server quirks; you'll have to test it against your customer's FTP server. As for verifying that the upload was successful, the only tools you have are (1) making sure there was no transport error during the upload, (2) validating the [file size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.getfilesize.aspx) when you're done.

The FTP server isn't going to support transactions, so you're going to have to manage that yourself, but this isn't really a complicated scenario. Use a transaction for the DB update; backing out the FTP upload is one call.

Answer (score -2):

try using Ftp with WCF

Comment: can u please give a more comprehensive answer? just fyi: i can only host things at my end - i do not have any liberty to do anything on remote server (ftp server) - that belongs to my client